# Profile2 profile

Tags: views, users

I am very new to Drupal but am good with coding (PHP, JS, whatever is required).
I want to set up a simple registration page that allows users to register using minimal fields (name, email, password, etc). ONCE THEY ARE registered and verified/okayed, I would like to give them an OPTION to fill in a profile form, which will have many optional fields they might want to share about themselves.

The profile form will always be available to registered users to edit/change.

What is the best way to achieve this? It seems the PROFILE2 module only adds fields to the registration page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oy, embarrasing. In the profile2 view, "edit" the individual profile, disable "Show during user account registration."

If those more experienced than me think this will help others, keep it... O/W delete this thread.

Comment: it's unlikely anyone with that authority will see this individual question, so I suggest you mark your own answer as accepted, so at least it doesn't keep showing up as unanswered.